# how can i go back in python

Tags: python

I have a question to ask you, I created a python code there is a menu with different options to choose from, as soon as I enter the first option I would like to create a command to return to the menu, I created a command input to choose the first option go back or otherwise the second option is to close the application, do you have any idea how I could go back to the please menu.

```
def Credits():
    print("********* WELCOME *********")
    n = input("\n\n1- Go back \n 2- Quit\n\n Please choose: ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Credits()
```

Comment: [Please do not post your code as image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Copy and paste your code into code tags.

Comment: use a [do-while](https://www.javatpoint.com/python-do-while-loop#:~:text=Python%20doesn't%20have%20do%2Dwhile%20loop.&text=The%20do%20while%20loop%20is,is%20executed%20at%20least%20once.) loop.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def Credits():
    while True:
        print("********* WELCOME *********")
        n = input("\n\n1- Go back \n2- Quit\n\n Please choose: ")
        if n == "2":
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Credits()   # this should be Credits not main
```

Comment: its not working I can't go back in the menu,

Comment: if you enter 1, you will go back to the welcome menu

Comment: it works well but the problem is that as soon as I run the program I go directly to the credits tab, so you have to change the location of the if__name home menu, or do you have to put it?

Comment: what do you want to do when you type 1. do you want to start the code all over again or do something else? to where does 'Go back' go back to?

Comment: when I run my program the home menu opens with 4 options, when I enter an option I have the choice to stay in the option, to return to the home menu so as not to restart the program or else to quit the program , with your code when I launch the program there is no host munu which starts there is direct the option but if I put back its operation I manage to return to the home menu

Answer (score 1):

```
def Credits():
    n = 1
    while n == 1:
        print("********* WELCOME *********")
        n = int(input("\n\n1- Go back \n 2- Quit\n\n Please choose: "))
        if n == 2:
          break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Credits()
```

Comment: its not working I can't go back in the menu,

Comment: Press 1 to go back

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code to give you a basic idea of how you could program it:

```
def mainMenue():
    print("I am in main menue now, please choose what you want to do:")
    choice = input(" 1) go to menue1 \n 2) go to menue2\n Your choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        menue1()
    elif choice == "2":
        menue2()

def menue1():
    print("I am in menue1, please choose what you want to do:")
    choice = input(" 1) go to home \n 2) go to menue2\n Your choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        mainMenue()
    elif choice == "2":
        menue2()

def menue2():
    print("I am in menue2, please choose what you want to do:")

    choice = input(" 1) go to home \n 2) go to menue1\n Your choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        mainMenue()
    elif choice == "2":
        menue1()
mainMenue()
```

Of course you can extend the program with much more menues, but that would be too much for this forum, since we don't want to write your whole program, but instead just give some hints how you could write it yourself

Comment: This will eventually lead to a `RecursionError` if the user doesn't exit the program soon enough.